# Mysql query always returning 0 results

Tags: php, mysql

What im trying to do is checking if a value exists in the table.If it does not exist a Failed message should be displayed

```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "myusers");
    print($string);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Failed1");
        exit();
    }

    else
    {
    if ($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `k1`='$string' AND 'k2'='$string2'"))
    {

    if($result->num_rows == 0)
    {
    printf("Failed2");
    }
```

This query is always returning Failed2 inspite of the fact that the values are existing in the table.what is the problem,The table has three values k0,k1 and k2 but i use only k1 and k2 for SELECT Query.Please help

EDIT:

I have changed the code ask you have suggested by removing ' but now the query will not execute and will lead to Failed3

```
<?php  

$string1=$_POST['value1'];
$string2=$_POST['value2'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "myusers");
print($string);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Failed1");
    exit();
}

else
{
    if ($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE k1='$string1' AND k2='$string2'"))
    {    
        if($result->num_rows == 0)
        {
            printf("Failed2");
        }
        else
        {
            //---------
        }
    }
    else
    {
         printf("Failed3");
    } 
}




?>
```

Comment: Have you checked apache/php logs? There could be some clues about the result of your query.

Comment: Where is `$string` coming from?  Just wondering, cause you arbitrarily stick it in SQL as if that's safe.  :P  If you didn't create it yourself, and particularly if it comes from or is derived from user input, consider using prepared statements.

Comment: @cHao see edit.security comes after getting the code to work

Comment: The code isn't working *because of broken SQL*.  Do you really think whatever you're doing with it isn't an issue?  Perhaps a little thought about security now would actually *fix* your issues.

Comment: @cHao im a novice,it would be better if you could tell me what is broken,rather than giving an abstract view

Comment: @techno: Clearly, either your table doesn't have the columns you think it does, or `$string1` or `$string2` has a value that's breaking your SQL.  The query that's there would work otherwise (if we ignore the fact that all it's going to return is a column full of `1`s).  Have you tried actually running this query in, say, phpmyadmin and seeing what happens?

Comment: @cHao Thanks i tried like this in phpmyadmin SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 'k1'='abc' AND 'k2'='123'

Comment: @cHao both abc and 123 exists in a row,but the query returned 0 rows

Comment: @techno: QUIT DOING 'this' FOR FIELD NAMES.  Quotes are for *values only*.  For identifiers (database/table/field names), use \`backticks\` or nothing.  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE k1 = 'abc' AND k2 = '123';`

Comment: i removed ' from k1 and k2 but an error show up after that#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'k1='abc' AND k2='123' at line 1

Comment: @techno: I'd suggest editing your post to include the exact query you tried in myadmin (in a code block; the backticks could be throwing everything off), and the error message.

Comment: @cHao i think i found the problem,the word k1 is shown in the same highlight color as users , i think there must be some database named k1?

Comment: @techno: MySQL doesn't care about that.  It still sounds like you're doing something outrageously wrong with quotes.  Stick the query in your post; i'm not going to diagnose quoting issues while Markdown is messing with any backticks it sees.

Comment: @cHao will do let me check.

Comment: @cHao That was the problem.Its fixed now :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

#### Typo here:

You used `'`s instead of backticks!

```
`k1`='$string' AND 'k2'='$string2'"
 ------------------^--^---------------- You have used single quotes!
```

Replace it with:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `k1`='$string' AND `k2`='$string2'
```

Comment: i have edited,but this had resulted in further error see edit

Comment: @techno What is the error been thrown from the MySQL Server? Can we have that?

Comment: Dude, get the exact error from MySQL Server, which can be got by `$mysqli->error`.

Comment: `printf("Failed3" . $mysqli->error);` or something equivalent. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: its showing syntax error in mysql query,i added the ' it worked and Failed2 is displayed.I tried appending the error code with failed2,but no error was displayed

Comment: I am not sure how to echo the error. Please check online how to display that error and let us know.

Comment: The question would be is the SELECT Query correct there are 3 columns in the table not 2

Comment: At the "Failed2" point, the query has succeeded, so there won't be an error to display.  It's just returning an empty result set, which is fully expected when you say something like `'k2' = 'anything that's not "k2"'`, which will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backticks and quotes from your table and column names, i.e.

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE  k1 ='$string' AND k2='$string2'
```

Comment: i have edited,but this had resulted in further error see edit

Comment: You'd have to extract the MySQL error code/message in order to see what is going wrong now.

Comment: its showing syntax error in mysql query,i added the ' it worked and Failed2 is displayed.I tried appending the error code with failed2,but no error was displayed

Comment: Next question would then be, what is the contents of `$string`? Since it is concatenated directly into the query, it is possible that `$string` contains a character such as `'` or a reserved word which breaks they query syntax.

Comment: i changed the query,with the ' its works and leads to failed2.There is no error,is the SELECT Query correct there are 3 columns in the table not 2

Comment: @techno: It's perfectly legit to not refer to all the columns in the table in one query.  As long as you don't need to select or filter by the data, there's not really a need to refer to that column.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a column called 1. You dont want to `Select 1 from users`

This will return one result only, if thats what you were looking for

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `k1`='$string' AND `k2`='$string2' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Good point, but that's probably not the cause of all these problems yet.  Even with `SELECT 1`, the query should succeed and just return a single column with the name and every value being `1`.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM table` is perfectly valid and will not fail when there is no column called `1`.

Comment: Ok fine, but even still, this is not what he means to accomplish.